# bash - Single quotes being added to double quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I'm writing a script to run a given program on a simulator while changing the argument supplied and I'm having a problem where bash keeps inserting single ticks around the double quotes that causes the simulator to crash spectacularly. How can I stop this from happening?

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
#./matrix_sim MM1.x86 1024 X86 gem5.opt

PROGRAM=$1
ARGUMENT=$2
ARCHI=$3
TARGET=$4

./gem5/build/$ARCHI/$TARGET gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./$PROGRAM -o \"$ARGUMENT\"
```

When I run this script, what actually is output is

```
./gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./MM1.x86 -o '"2"'
```

But what I really want to happen is this

```
./gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./MM1.x86 -o "2"
```

How do I get rid of the single ticks on output?

Comment: Do you want the program to actually get `"2"` as the option, or is `2` the right thing to pass? If the latter, just use `"$ARGUMENT"`.

Comment: Does the script need to hang around? If not, use `exec ./gem5/...` to make it replace itself with that final command.

Comment: You mean, in the debug output of `bash -x`?

Comment: While the question is unclear, somehow google still finds it, someone who understands this should edit it, and not just bash -x, but also set -x in the script causes this behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does not add single quotes to your string. The single quotes are how it makes the output of the `set -x` trace visually unambiguous. In bash, `set -x` produces visually unambiguous output by putting single quotes around strings that contain shell special characters (whitespace and `` !"#$&\()*;<>?[\]^`{|}~ ``). Here, you're tracing a command which takes a parameter containing a `"`, so bash prints it out with single quotes around it to make it clear that the `"` is a literal character in the string and not something in the shell source syntax.

It seems that you didn't want to have a *double quote* in the argument. So don't put one.

You do need double quotes around variable expansions, but that's double quotes, in the shell syntax, not putting a quoted double quote so that a double quote character ends up in the string.

```
"./gem5/build/$ARCHI/$TARGET" gem5/configs/example/se.py -c "./$PROGRAM" -o "$ARGUMENT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `"$ARGUMENT"`:

```
./gem5/build/$ARCHI/$TARGET gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./$PROGRAM -o "$ARGUMENT"
```

Bash will add single quotes (in e.g. the `set -x` tracing output) when you use `\"$ARGUMENT\"` because you're making the double quotes part of the argument's value (this is most likely *not* what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate:

```
$ ./in.sh program arg arch target
./gem5/build/arch/target gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./program -o "arg"
$ cat in.sh
#!/bin/bash
#./matrix_sim MM1.x86 1024 X86 gem5.opt

PROGRAM=$1
ARGUMENT=$2
ARCHI=$3
TARGET=$4

echo ./gem5/build/$ARCHI/$TARGET gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./$PROGRAM -o \"$ARGUMENT\"
```

I've tried many manipulations to try to replicate what you're seeing and am unable to do so.

You could perhaps try:

```
ARGUMENT="\"$2\""
```

and then removing the escaped quotes around your invocation:

```
echo ./gem5/build/$ARCHI/$TARGET gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./$PROGRAM -o "$ARGUMENT"
```

Comment: I'm supposing he's looking at trace output from `set -x`.