# Unexpected quotes in zsh trace

Tags: zsh, debugging

I've got a *third party* script that receives command line arguments in this form:

```
$ ./script.sh --params a=123 b=456
```

There is a file xyz.txt with this contents:

```
c=3
d=4
```

I'm trying to use its contents as paremeters for the script, but the script complains about not receiving proper arguments. When I do `set -x`, I can see that each of my arguments is enclosed in single quotes (so the third party script cannot handle them)

```
$ set -x
$ ./script.sh --params $(cat xyz.txt)

....
+-zsh:20> cat xyz.txt
+-zsh:20> ./script.sh --params 'c=3' 'd=4'
```

Tried in bash (also with `set -x`) and the result is as expected (no single quotes):

```
$ set -x
$ ./script.sh --params $(cat xyz.txt)

++ cat xyz.txt
+ ./script.sh --params c=3 d=4
```

This behaviour is not present if the values in the file do not contain an equals sign. E.g.

```
e-5
f-6

... 
+-zsh:20> ./script.sh --params e-5 f-6
```

I tried disabling as many `setopt` as I could without success.

How can I prevent Zsh from enclosing my arguments in single quotes when they contain equal sign (mimic Bash behaviour)?

Answer (score 3):

There are no single quotes inserted into the arguments by the shell.

Proof:

```
$ cat file
c=3
d=4
$ printf 'Argument: >>%s<<\n' $(cat file)
Argument: >>c=3<<
Argument: >>d=4<<
```

This shows that the the two lines read from `file` are properly split into two separate arguments and handed to the `printf` utility without the addition of single quotes.

Notice how the output does not change when running under `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ printf 'Argument: >>%s<<\n' $(cat file)
+/usr/local/bin/zsh:11> cat file
+/usr/local/bin/zsh:11> printf 'Argument: >>%s<<\n' 'c=3' 'd=4'
Argument: >>c=3<<
Argument: >>d=4<<
```

The single quotes are not part of the arguments passed to your script. They are just inserted as a visual aid by the shell for the sake of the trace output (which is debugging output and which can not be used or interpreted as input to the shell).  The `zsh` and `bash` shells formats their tracing output slightly differently, that's all.

If you are experiencing issues with running your script from the `zsh` shell, then these are not due to the shell modifying the data in the file.

Comment: `=` is also a special operator in the zsh syntax so needs quoted at least in some contexts  (compare `echo =ls` vs `echo '=ls'`). In `bash` it's special as well in that it causes what follows to be subject to tilde expansion (at least when what's before looks like a valid variable name). You'll notice `bash -xc 'echo +=~'` or `bash -xc 'echo a=\~'` outputs `echo 'a=~'` and `echo '+=~'` (even if those quotes are not strictly necessary in that case). `bash -xc 'a\=x'` outputs `a=x` which is a bug though (as `a=x` would assign `x` to `a` instead of running the `a=x` command). `zsh`'s OK.