# How to pass a pattern to grep as a variable?

Tags: linux, grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use the following command, as part of a script, to backup from my W10 machine with WSL to a Debian box:

`rsync -PaSh --stats --delete -e 'ssh -p XXXX -i ~/keys/key' /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/ user@hostname.com:/home/user/ 2>> /mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/output.txt | grep -e 'Number of regular files' -e 'Total transferred' -e 'bytes/sec' >> /mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/output.txt`

This works fine and correctly pipes output.

To simplify, I'd like to replace the `grep` pattern with a variable:

`arguments="-e 'Number of regular files' -e 'Total transferred' -e 'bytes/sec'"`

`rsync -PaSh --stats --delete -e 'ssh -p XXXX -i ~/keys/key' /mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/ user@hostname.com:/home/user/ 2>> /mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/output.txt | grep $arguments >> /mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/output.txt`

This gives me:

```
grep: of: No such file or directory
grep: regular: No such file or directory
grep: files': No such file or directory
grep: transferred': No such file or directory
```

How can I tell `grep` to correctly recognise the spaces?

Comment: Also related: [Using shell variables for command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459367/using-shell-variables-for-command-options)

Comment: the shell isn't a macro processor: quotes and other syntax elements that you've stored in a variable don't get used as shell syntax just by expanding the variable any more than they would in other programming language. Put the arguments in an array as individual strings and use that array. `args=(-e 'Number of regular files' -e 'Total transferred' ...)` etc.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is the pseudo-array `"$@"` described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable. Thanks for your replies.