# Possibilities to Append the Command in Variable

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a variable that contains a find command

```
LST_FILE=$(find . -type f \( -name -o '*xml*' -o -name -o '*log*' \) -mmin 180)
```

Is it possible to append the command ? I mean like this

```
LST_FILE+=$(-delete)
```

or probably

```
DEL=$(-delete)
LST_FILE+=${DEL}
```

I need to know because I have several find commands that need to perform and it has different options for each commands, so I decided to put the command into variable and plan to append it with of each options regarding to the condition..

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `LST_FILE=$(...)`? That doesn't put the command into the variable, but its result.

Comment: @DonHolgo ahh yes I just found out recently, I'm new to this shellscript thing.. thankss

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your `find` command is wrong. You want this:

```
find . -type f \( -name  '*xml*' -o -name '*log*' \) -mmin 180
```

Next, your variable does not contain a `find` command, it contains the *output* of a `find` command. I suspect what you really want is this:

```
find_command='find . -type f ( -name  *xml* -o -name *log ) -mmin 180'
del="-delete"
```

Then, to add the `-delete` to the command, you can do:

```
find_command="$find_command $del"
```

And to execute it, you would simply run:

```
$find_command
```

But please read [Using shell variables for command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459367/using-shell-variables-for-command-options) and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050. There are a lot of complications when trying to use variables to run commands.

Comment: You have uneven number of single quotes in your `find_command=` line, and should be using an array (or the positional parameters) rather than a string.

Comment: Thanks, @Kusalananda, fixed the quotes. And yes, of course you should be using an array, that's what the two references I link to at the end explain. I just also wanted to point out the other issues. This specific case does work as a string, so I thought it would be useful to show how _and_ link to resources showing the Right Way®.